# tf.reset_default_graph memory leak

Tags: python, session, tensorflow, graph, memory-leaks

I'm trying to run some experiments with automatic hyperparameter optimization in TensorFlow, so the main loop of my program needs to repeatedly create a graph, run it, destroy it to free up memory for the next iteration. To this end, I have:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
```

This appears to work in all ways except one: each time round the loop, the program leaks several hundred megabytes of memory. I'm not allocating any other kinds of complex data structure that would be candidates for the memory leak, so presumably I'm using `tf.reset_default_graph` incorrectly.

What am I doing wrong?

Program is at https://github.com/russellw/tf-examples/blob/master/sko_lstm.py

Comment: Can you show some evidence? My lib uses `tf.reset_default_graph()` also for hyper-parameter tuning and it's able to process lots of graphs, way more than 100. The leak is somewhere else

Comment: @Maxim Okay, added link to program. I'm not seeing anywhere else the leak could be; am I missing something?

Comment: Ah, I think I got it. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `tf.InteractiveSession()` with `with tf.Session():` statement. The former is designed to be used in a console, so it starts, makes itself a default and doesn't free the resources unless you call `sess.close()` manually (which is so easy to forget, on top of that you should consider exceptions). As a result, your code ends up with lots of parallel sessions, each holding its resources. `tf.reset_default_graph()` won't free those resources while the session is active.

`with` statement ensures the context manager will call `__exit__` and the session will be closed.